# Having trouble copying an ArrayList

Tags: java

This might be a bit of a stupid question, but I can't figure this out! I'm working on a minigame that involves one player being randomly selected as the terminator, and all the rest as weaklings. I have an ArrayList of players, and I can get it to choose the terminator, and then I need it to copy players into weaklings, but skip terminator. The code I'm using doesn't copy anything at all into weaklings. Here's the code I'm using, could someone a bit more experienced help me out please:

```
            
            for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++ ) {
                
                if (!players.get(i).contentEquals(terminator)) {
                    
                    players.add(players.get(i));
                    
                }
                
            }
            
            System.out.print("The other players are: " + weaklings + ".");
                
            }
```

Comment: Why don't you put every player in a weaklings list and then just remove the terminator and save it (via the return value)?

Answer (score 2):

You add to the `players` again: `players.add`, instead of `weaklings.add`.

Comment: OH MY GOD I'M SO DUMB 